# How to include external dependencies in Weblogic MbeanMaker MJF JAR?

Tags: java, jar, mbeans

I am following the tutorial at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13718/atn.htm to create a custom authentication provider for Weblogic 10.3.6.

So far all the examples of custom authentication providers I have found on the web are all using either pure java code or weblogic's libraries and have no external dependencies:

- http://download.oracle.com/otn/samplecode/dbuserprovider.zip
- http://danielveselka.blogspot.com/2012/04/mock-weblogic-login-module-identity.html
- https://github.com/arykov/weblogic-security-provider-mvn
- https://gist.github.com/kares/356576

Weblogic uses it's custom command line tool for creating .jars/MJFs.

If I simply import external libraries, then my project compiles fine, but at runtime it throws `ClassNotFoundException`.

I also tried manually adding the dependency jar contents to my jar, but no luck.

So my question is: How do I use/include external libraries in weblogic MJF?

Answer (score 0):

Ok my second approach was right, my mistake was that I was including .java source code of the dependency instead of compiled .class files.

So the solution is to exteract/copy the contents of the dependency .jar (compiled .class files of the dependency, not the source code) to your jar's root.

This is ugly and dirty and horrible but so is weblogic's plugin system.